# $.getjson data is not working, I have parseerror for textstatus

Tags: php, jquery, json, typeahead

I have two files
Search.php is file 1, and it is finishing as below 2 lines of code

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
print(json_encode($places, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

file 2 is search function inside Javacript extension and I am using $.getjson to get those above JSON data my code is as follow

```
function search(query, cb)
{
    // get places matching query (asynchronously)
    var parameters = {
        geo: query
    };
    $.getJSON("search.php", parameters)
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        // call typeahead's callback with search results (i.e., places)
        cb(data);   
        console.log("bill");
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        // log error to browser's console
        console.log("mistake is: " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

I am unable to get JSON data through .done, search function always fail.
Console.log shows parseerror for textstatus.
Anyone to help me to figure out why search function isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: basic debugging: convert to a plain `$.get()`, then inspect what you're getting back from the server. if you're sending out **ANYTHING** other than a valid json string, you're going to get parse errors. e.g. php warnings/errors, html, blah blah blah.

Comment: Data back from server is JSON correct data

Comment: Can you provide the content of the response?

Comment: content is   [
    {
        "projectnb": "F-DDD",
        "rank": "B"
    },
    {
        "projectnb": "F-GGG",
        "rank": "B"
    }]

Comment: I could actually solved it by no longer using $.getjson (Jquery) but using simple AJAX with javascript only.